# Как убрать автоматическую цифровую подпись Debug версии Android приложения?

Tags: android-studio

Вот сама проблема:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:packageDebug' (type 'PackageApplication').

> File 'D:\123\app\D:Users\huawei\Desktop.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile' does not exist.
> Не понимаю почему путь дублируется дважды и не понимаю как Android Studio сама создает на диске D путь Desktop.android\debug.keystore
> Цифровая подпись мне не нужна, приложение я никуда не выкладываю

Answer (score 0):

> File 'D:\123\app\D:Users\huawei\Desktop.android\debug.keystore'
> specified for property 'signingConfig.signingConfigData.storeFile'
> does not exist.

Наверняка файл удалён и перемещён в другое место. Поэтому студия и ругается.

> Цифровая подпись мне не нужна, приложение я никуда не выкладываю

Без цифровой подписи приложение нельзя установить на телефон. Совсем нельзя. Даже, если речь идёт об отладке и Вы используете эмулятор. Так устроен Android.

Поэтому студия автоматически создаёт цифровую подпись для разработки и также автоматически подписывает ей приложение при сборке для тестового запуска на телефоне или эмуляторе.

Поэтому убрать цифровую подпись не получится. Но, самое главное, это и не требуется.

Comment: Но ведь у меня не компилируется пустой проект даже...

Comment: А студию и настройки я ставил заново, файл на месте должен быть